# Is there a way to read request body before spring's MultipartParser in Spring webflux?

Tags: file-upload, spring-webflux, multipart

I have spring boot 3.1 project. I am using custom authentication implemented with WebFilter. It reads request HTTP method, url and body and validates signature in header. This is already implemented and working part. This authentication serves for hardware device authentication with private/public key. Simplified code looks like this:

```kotlin
@Component
class SecurityAuthenticationFilter : WebFilter {

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        if (!isSecuredPath(exchange.request.uri.path)) {
            LOG.debug("Unsecured request, skipping ..")
            return chain.filter(exchange)
        }
        return checkRequestSignature(getPublicKey(), exchange, chain)
    }

    private fun checkRequestSignature(publicKey: PublicKey,
                                      exchange: ServerWebExchange,
                                      chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        return DataBufferUtils.join(exchange.request.body.map { it })
            .map { dataBuffer: DataBuffer ->
                val bytes = ByteArray(dataBuffer.readableByteCount())
                dataBuffer.read(bytes)
                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer)
                bytes
            }
            .defaultIfEmpty(ByteArray(0))
            .flatMap { bytes: ByteArray ->

                validateRequestSignature(publicKey, exchange, Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes))

                val mutatedRequest: ServerHttpRequest =
                    object : ServerHttpRequestDecorator(exchange.request) {
                        override fun getBody(): Flux<DataBuffer> {
                            return Flux.just(exchange.response.bufferFactory().wrap(bytes))
                        }
                    }
                chain.filter(
                    exchange.mutate().request(mutatedRequest).build()
                )
            }
    }

    
    private fun validateRequestSignature(pubKey: PublicKey, exchange: ServerWebExchange, body: String) {
        val signature = getHeader(exchange, KIOSK_REQ_SIGNATURE_HEADER)
            ?: unauthorized("Missing signature header")

        val signingData = with(exchange.request) {
            val path = if (uri.query == null || uri.query.isEmpty()) uri.path else uri.path + "?" + uri.query
            method.name() + path + body
        }
        if (!verifySignature(signingData, signature, pubKey)) {
            LOG.trace("Request signature does not match. Incoming signature: $signature , signing data: $signingData")
            unauthorized("Request signature does not match.")
        }
    }

    private fun getHeader(exchange: ServerWebExchange, headerName: String) = exchange.request.headers.getFirst(headerName)

    private fun unauthorized(text: String = ""): Nothing = throw ResponseStatusException(UNAUTHORIZED, text)

    private fun isSecuredPath(path: String) = path.startsWith("/api/")
    
    private fun getPublicKey() = TODO()
}
```

Important part is `checkRequestSignature` where I read request body and mutate request to be able use body in next processing.

Now I have file upload controller that has same security. Implemented simply with:

```kotlin
@PostMapping("/upload", consumes = [MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
fun upload(@RequestPart("file") file: Mono<FilePart>) : Mono<Void> = .....
```

It works fine without this SecurityAuthenticationFilter enabled. But when enabled it ends with following error:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: Could not find first boundary
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartParser$PreambleState.onComplete(MultipartParser.java:339) ~[spring-web-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.create(Flux.java:646)
    org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartParser.parse(MultipartParser.java:99)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *_____________Flux.create ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartParser.parse(MultipartParser.java:99)
    |_       Flux.windowUntil ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.lambda$read$1(DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.java:231)
    |_         Flux.concatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.lambda$read$1(DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.java:232)
    *______________Flux.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.read(DefaultPartHttpMessageReader.java:220)
    |_   Flux.collectMultimap ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageReader.readMono(MultipartHttpMessageReader.java:117)
    |_          Mono.doOnNext ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageReader.readMono(MultipartHttpMessageReader.java:118)
    |_               Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageReader.readMono(MultipartHttpMessageReader.java:124)
    |_          Mono.doOnNext ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange.initMultipartData(DefaultServerWebExchange.java:173)
    |_     Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange.initMultipartData(DefaultServerWebExchange.java:174)
    |_             Mono.cache ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.adapter.DefaultServerWebExchange.initMultipartData(DefaultServerWebExchange.java:175)
    |_   Mono.flatMapIterable ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.getPartValues(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:114)
    |_              Mono.from ⇢ at org.springframework.core.ReactiveAdapter.fromPublisher(ReactiveAdapter.java:121)
    |_           Mono.flatMap ⇢ at com.generalbytes.dnameter.kioskserver.service.KioskService.uploadFile(KioskService.kt:67)
    |_             checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.generalbytes.dnameter.kioskserver.api.controller.KioskController#upload(String, KioskFileUploadType, Mono) [DispatcherHandler]
    |_     Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleResult(DispatcherHandler.java:194)
    *____________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.lambda$handleResult$8(DispatcherHandler.java:195)
    *____________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handleRequestWith(DispatcherHandler.java:184)
    *____________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.DispatcherHandler.handle(DispatcherHandler.java:154)
    *______________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:106)
    *____________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at com.generalbytes.dnameter.kioskserver.http.SecurityAuthenticationFilter.checkRequestSignature(SecurityAuthenticationFilter.kt:81)
    |_             checkpoint ⇢ com.generalbytes.dnameter.kioskserver.http.SecurityAuthenticationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *______________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:106)
    |_         Mono.doFinally ⇢ at com.generalbytes.dnameter.kioskserver.http.HttpLoggingFilter.filter(HttpLoggingFilter.kt:18)
    |_             checkpoint ⇢ com.generalbytes.dnameter.kioskserver.http.HttpLoggingFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *______________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:106)
    |_          Mono.doOnEach ⇢ at org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter.filter(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
    |_        Mono.doOnCancel ⇢ at org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter.filter(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:119)
    |_      Mono.contextWrite ⇢ at org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter.filter(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:123)
    *__Mono.transformDeferred ⇢ at org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter.filter(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:102)
    |_             checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    *______________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain.filter(DefaultWebFilterChain.java:106)
    |_     Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:77)
    *______________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.server.handler.ExceptionHandlingWebHandler$CheckpointInsertingHandler.handle(ExceptionHandlingWebHandler.java:98)
    |_             checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/kapi/v1/kiosk/upload?type=CAMERA_PHOTO" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

After some time and debugging and have come to conclusion that request body is already consumed. And my debugging confirmed this. I can see that  `org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartParser` and `org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageReader` from spring uses reference to original request, not the mutated one.

After a day a could not solve this. I am not so familiar with spring webflux and spring reactor yet. So I have multiple questions now:

- Am I doing something wrong that I am not aware of?
- Or is there a way how to do this? Read request body for signature verification before request is processed with spring webflux and multipart upload?
- I am not so familiar with spring webflux code. Is this behavior intended or could be a bug?

Thank you